# Fiddler won't filter results in Windows 7

Tags: http, windows-7, fiddler

I'm having some trouble getting Fiddler to apply any filters to the session results, or to restrict the results by process or host, or anything else. I'm running Fiddler as administrator in Windows 7 (otherwise it shows no results), and under filters I've tried a number of different settings, including "Hide the following Hosts," "Show only the following Hosts," and "Show only Intranet Hosts." I have "Show only Internet Explorer traffic" checked. But in all cases the sessions list still returns all outgoing HTTP traffic. These are requests from other browser windows and applications (for example, constant requests to mail.google.com and api.twitter.com if I happen to have those open). Of course I can close some of these browser tabs or apps, but that doesn't entirely address the problem and I actually need several of those things open while debugging. I'm getting by, but this is greatly interfering with Fiddler's usefulness.

I've tried using the process filter by dragging the crosshairs to Internet Explorer. But it still shows requests from Chrome and everything else. If I select "Hide Image Requests" under Rules, images still show up in my sessions list.

I've also tried directly editing the CustomRules.js file to hide a subset of host names, and then restarted Fiddler. In both that file and the application settings, I've tried several variations of the complete hostname, partial host names, and wildcards. No luck - every request still shows up in the sessions list.

So it's basically like none of the rules are being applied to the application, no matter what I try. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the exact version number of Fiddler that you're using? The current version is v2.3.2.6, so if you're not using that, please upgrade and see if that helps.

If that does not resolve the problem, please tell me what you see in the Process column in the session list for requests that are coming from your browser.

> *I'm running Fiddler as administrator in Windows 7 (otherwise it shows no results)*

That suggests that your computer has the "Use Machine Proxy Settings only" group policy applied. This group policy causes IE to ignore the per-user proxy settings that Fiddler normally sets. Fiddler can only set the per-machine proxy settings when run as Administrator.

Comment: Just upgraded to v2.3.2.6 and nothing changed. (Kind of surprised I hadn't done that.)

Comment: The Process column has iexplore:2948 (which mostly contains what I want to see) and chrome:4980. The group policy setting makes sense for that problem, but would it impact the non-filtering issue?

Comment: No, GP won't impact Filtering. Does the status bar filter work? Do you see any HTTP Protocol Violations mentioned on the LOG screen? If you delete your CustomRules.JS file, do you see a change? Please save a sample of the sessions (that you expect to be hidden) using the Session Archive Zip format and email me the file using the option on the Help menu. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, deleting CustomRules.js did the trick! Thanks for the help.